# Inno Setup: Task without checkbox

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to perform a task without asking the user if he wants to do this:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; 

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\CustomerOffice"; Filename: "{app}\CO.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon;
```

However, Inno Setup always shows a checkbox allowing the user to disable it.
Is there a way to not show such a checkbox at all?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the item from the `[Tasks]` section (which will remove the check box from task list) along with the `Tasks` parameter from the `[Icons]` section entry (which will remove the optional processing of that icon entry). So what remains is just this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\CustomerOffice"; Filename: "{app}\CO.exe"
```